# Create a Function and Find the Largest Value in the Dataset and Find its Position of Row and Column using an IF statement & a Loop

Tags: r

I need to create a Function called max.mat (), and use that function to identify the position (Row and Column) within the Matrix associated with the largest value of the dataSet. I was told that to create this function I should be using 2 things: 1) a "if statement" 2) a loop

Comment: Read the following documentation: `?matrix` to create a test matrix, `?for` to run a for loop, `if` to construct an if statement. Once you've built a matrix, read `help("[")` to see how to access elements of the matrix. This should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Is it required to use IF statement and Loop? because you can easily do it using other functions...or actually function...

Comment: There is no need for a long introduction. Get to the point and most importantly, provide a small dataset. It should be simulated or used using `dput`, along with the code you tried. Showing some effort, in whatever shape, form or size is always welcome.

Comment: Hey Stacie, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be sure to check out [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how you can improve this question and its reception here.

Answer (score 2):

If you REALLY need to use a for loop and an if statement this is one way to go. But first let's make a matrix with a bunch of random numbers.

```
set.seed(100)
mymat <- matrix(runif(100), ncol = 10, nrow = 10)
```

Now, we create the function.

```
max.mat <- function(x){
  # iterate through the columns from 1 to the max number
  # of columns
for(i in 1:ncol(x)){
  # iterate through each number in a column
  for(j in 1:nrow(x)){
    # if the jth number in the ith column equals the maximum
    # value of x
    if(x[j,i] == max(x)){
      # return a vector that says what j and i are
      return(c("row" = j, "col" = i))
      # then stop looping through stuff
      stop()
      }
    }
  }
}

max.mat(mymat)
     row col
[1,]   9   4
```

This uses two for loops. We could simplify it down to one if we wanted, but we could also just not use the loops

```
max.mat.easier <- function(x){
  which(x == max(x), arr.ind = TRUE)
}

max.mat.easier(mymat)
     row col
[1,]   9   4
```

Comment: If you need to get the maximum value as well you should be able to edit this code to return it as well.